# Trying to send encrypted text via URI - /uDDBA causing "URIError: URI Malformed"

Tags: javascript, unicode, uri, encryption-symmetric

Simple Code:

```
encodeURIComponent("\uDDBA")
```

Result:

```
URIError: URI malformed
```

I am trying to do a simple encryption that will take some user input text, and a password, and it will then encrypt that text and save it to the server.

Basically I am trying to encode a letter "t" - and the algorithm has determined that the  should be 56762 or DDBA in hex.

But it looks like certain hex values will result in errors if I try to encode that character using encodeURIComponent.

How can I solve this?

I basically need to know the available range of characters that can properly pass through encodeURIComponent in javascript.

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
var xor = 0xDDCE;

var plainText = "t".charCodeAt(0);
var encoded = plainText ^ xor;
var encodedChar = String.fromCharCode(encoded);
var uri = "/someuri?character=" + encodeURIComponent(encodedChar);

// This is how i would get the plain text back
var decoded = encodedChar.charCodeAt(0) ^ xor;
var decodedChar = String.fromCharCode(decoded);
```

This is a very simplified version, where the xor value is static. In the real case the xor value will be calculated based on a bunch of variables.

Assume "/someuri" is not built by me, and wasn't really originally built to receive encrypted data, I am merely trying to use this URI.

Also, my encryption algorithm can be changed. The `xor` value will be generated using a fairly simple algorithm using a user entered password, and the position of the character.

I was thinking of one way to make this work would be to reduce the total number of possible output characters and perform a mapping of some kind... but I can't really picture the code for that.

Edit:

Comments on the security of my choice of encryption is appreciated; however, the actual data security aspect is not as important. I just want to prevent "average" people from being able to read the output encrypted text (assume there can be lots of it)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the average people not to see the text, just use a POST request or Base64.

As for actual security this is completely useless. An attacker doesn't need to know what the plaintext is, all he needs to know what
the user sent to your site and send the same data back themself. The only way to prevent this is to use SSL everywhere on your site. 
If they wanted, they could use your algorithm found on the page's source code to decrypt it.

---

It is kinda terrible that Javascript strings don't validate their state right away as it could be done basically for free. Javascript
strings are associated with [UTF-16* encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) where not all sequences are valid. It is not valid to have a unit value between 0xD800 - 0xDBFF
when it is not immediatelly followed be 0xDC00 - 0xDFFF. And it is not valid to have 0xDC00 - 0xDFFF if the previous unit value is not 
0xD800 - 0xDBFF.

Many things can lead strings to violate this and because strings don't validate themselves you will only see an error much later.

You could always go 8 bits at a time and it'll work.

```
var xor = 0xDDCE;

var input = "t",
    output = "",
    i = 0,
    ch;

while( isFinite( ch = input.charCodeAt(i++) ) {
    var xored = ch ^ xor;
    output += String.fromCharCode(
        (xored & 0xFF00) >> 8,
        xored & 0xFF
    );
}

//output is "Ýº", or 0x00DD 0x00BA, each char is always 0x00XX
```

---

*The specification allows using UCS-2 as well but I have never seen this. If you want to be sure:

```
function areStringsUTF16() {
    try {
        var str = decodeURIComponent("%F0%A0%80%80");
        return str.charCodeAt(0) === 0xd840 &&
               str.charCodeAt(1) === 0xdc00;
    }
    catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will study your answer a little bit. But for the data security uselessness, I want to mention one thing - I wouldn't care if an attacker tries to pretend to know the plain text, I really only care that the attacker cannot read the plain text. The encrypted data is displayed on a public web site that I do not own, and I want only me and people that I've given the password to be able to read it. Of course someone could break the security, I just want something sufficient for the average person.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,

I am going to attempt to answer my own question

Run this code:

```
 (function() {
    var last = null;
    for ( var idx = 0; idx < 0xffff; idx++) {
        try {
            encodeURIComponent(String.fromCharCode(idx));
        } catch (e) {
            if (idx != last + 1) {
                console.log(idx);
            }
            last = idx;
        }
    }
    console.log(last);
 })();
```

It will result in

```
55296
57343
```

Which means any values between \uD800 and \uDFFF are not allowed.

When I was writing this, it occurred to me that I should just write a for loop and test everything.